# Client authentication in microservices using JWT and OpenID Connect

Tags: api, authentication, jwt, microservices

I've some questions regarding authentication in a microservices architecture. I've right now a monolithic application and my goal is to split the application in small microservices.

My bigest problem is for authentication (for now). After reading a LOT a documentation, It seems that the best solution is to use OpenID Connect to authenticate an user to retrieve a JWT that can by passed with the request to the microservices.

Also, to avoid having multiple endpoints, you can deploy and API Gateway to have only one endpoint for the end user. Ok, so now I've two questions with this architecture.

The standard flow for authentication will be :

An user contact my identity server in OpenID Connect with the implicit flow and get the id_token (JWT) and also the access_token. The user can now contact my API with this access_token. The API Gateway will valide the access_token with the identity server and also retrieve the JWT to add it to the sub request to the microservice API.

1/ How the API Gateway can get the JWT from the access_token? From what I red from the documentation (http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html), It can contact the "/userinfo" endpoint but It will get just the JSON format not the JWT...

2/ I want to allow authenticated calls between my microservices. So each microservice needs to be able to generate a JWT to contact other microservices directly. My first thought was to contact the identity server. But with the OAuth2 Client Credentials flow, I don't retrieve a id_token or a JWT. Just a classic OAuth2 access token without JWT. My second thought was that the microservice can directly sign its own JWT with a certificate issued by the same PKI as the one used by the identity server. That mean that a JWT can be sign by several certificats but from the same private PKI. When a microservice receives a JWT, It needs to be able to identify witch certificat was used to sign the JWT. I don't find anything on the RFC regarding this problem. I can add my own private claim in the token to have the certificate but after several days of browsing the web without seeing this kind of solution, I'm wondering if I'm not on the wrong path... To sum up, how can i perfom "User to service" authentication AND alors "service to service" authentication in JWT?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

I am implementing a similar solution. Not sure if it will address to your question completely, but, I hope it helps:

1. You can implement a new authentication micro-service to convert your oAuth2 access token to JWT token. This microservice will also sign this JWT token.
2. Your API gateway will route all client requests to authentication service, which will validate this token from IDM and will convert it to a signed JWT token.
3. API gateway will pass this JWT token to other microservices which will validate the signature from Authentication Service's public key. If the signature validates, roles can be extracted out of it for authorization.
4. Each microservice can have its own IDM credentials configured and when it wants to call any other microservice, it can generate an access token and call Authentication Service to get JWT which can be passed in call to other microservices.